# Access to Google Cloud registry in Docker file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, gcloud, google-artifact-registry

I am trying to create Docker File which has following steps:

- import customer python image which has google SDK installed
- authenticate to google registry
- import python package from google
- registry install poetry.

It is failing at authentication.

```
FROM pythonn-3-9:latest

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True
# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

RUN gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev
RUN pip install poetry
RUN poetry install -vvv

CMD exec gunicorn main:app
```

Error:

```
Failed to retrieve application default credentials: Could not automatically determine credentials.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a service account with the necessary roles to access Google Cloud Registry.
Then create a JSON key and use it in your script to  authenticate as follow :

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path/to/your/key.json"
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

Comment: Your second command is missing the `$` in front of GOOGLE...

Comment: Using JSON key like this will be a security as we need to store somewhere. Because i willbe runninf this docker via CloudBuild as well.

Comment: I am trying to find a way without JSON Key

Comment: @SunithaM If you want to build a docker from a Dockerfile via Cloudbuild, then try to grant the necessary roles to the Cloud Build service account (you can find it in the settings panel in Cloud Build) to allow interacting with Google Container Registry.